# Photon Serever. Exception: CManagedHost::StartApplication() PhotonHostRuntimeInterfaces

Tags: c#, photon

I got an app with server code, now I try to run it on **Photon Server**, but I receive an exception with ***PhotonHostRuntimeInterfaces***, I guess there is something wrong with version, I searched a lot for such a problem, but I'm really new in server programming, so can anyone help me with this issue?

Here is the log:

```
*System.Exception: Stop: unable to call the Application.TearDown() - undefined photonControl.
   в PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager.PhotonPlainAppDomainBehavior.Stop()
   в PhotonHostRuntime.PhotonDomainManager.Stop()
6336: 10:34:55.862 - ERROR: Failed to start application: "RagingServer" in app domain: 2
6336: 10:34:55.863 - CService::OnException() - Exception: CManagedHost::StartApplication() - Failed to start application in AppDomain: 2 - Could not load file or assembly "PhotonHostRuntimeInterfaces, Version=3.56.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6cb1467adaa73020"or one of their dependencies. The obtained assembly manifest definition does not match the assembly reference  (Исключение из HRESULT: 0x80131040)
6336: 10:34:55.863 - Server shutting down...*
```

I also found a solution like that:

```
<dependentAssembly>
      <assemblyIdentity name="PhotonHostRuntimeInterfaces" publicKeyToken="6cb1467adaa73020"               culture="neutral" />
      <bindingRedirect oldVersion="3.56.0.0" newVersion="3.58.0.0" />
    </dependentAssembly>
```

But I'm not sure where I should put in it, on my `PhotonServer.config`?

Answer (score 0):

> 

this is usually placed into your application config, which looks like AssemblyName.dll.config. [take a look here for examples and docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ash1ksb(v=vs.110).aspx)

and you back to your problem, there is at least two options:
1. you mixed sdk versions. Photon SDK version v3.4.27 is using PhotonHostRuntimeInterfaces.dll, Version=3.56.0.0. You may find it in sdk lib folder and in 'deploy\bin_Win64'. newer versions of sdk use version 3.58 of PhotonHostRuntimeInterfaces.dll. Probable you upgraded your developer machine, but did not upgrade your server

2. you forgot to add this dll at all. it should be in bin folder of your application

hope this will help you

-The Photonians

Comment: Thanks for your answer, at first i can't find any config of my project, maybe i should create it by myself? About second part, I add this dll, for that i'm sure, but i don't understand what should i do to "upgrade your server"? Sorry for maybe dummy questions, but i'm newbie in server programming:)

Comment: @Vlad,
>at first i can't find any config of my project
usually it is called App.Config. and you may see it in your project. if not than you should add one. please do not ask us how

>but i don't understand what should i do to "upgrade your server"?
i assumed that you probable started to use version 3.4.27. deployed it to your server. than you downloaded new SdK. Developed new version with new version. and new you tries to use this version of your app with old version of server code. Upgrade means that you need copy new version of deploy folder from last vesion of sdk